# How are ".h" header files able to "see" the contents of their corresponding ".cpp" files?

Tags: visual-c++, intellisense

Let me first begin by providing a little background to explain the motivation for this question:

I've always been under the impression that a `#include` directive in C++ has the net effect of inserting the contents of the included file at the point where the directive appears.

For example, when the preprocessor encounters `#include "myInclude.h`, it would simply replace that directive with the content found in the file `myInclude.h`

You can imagine my surprise when, earlier today, I was editing some code in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 and the IntelliSense feature was flagging a class declaration in a header as undefined **until** I included that header in it's corresponding .cpp file.

Here are the specific files involved:

```
// myInclude.h
#pragma once
class MyDlg : public CDialogImpl<MyDlg>
{
// Omitted code
};
```

```
// myInclude.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "myInclude.h" // <-- if this line is here, intellisense in myInclude.h is happy
                       //     but if commented out, CDialogImpl is undefined

// Omitted implementation code
```

```
// stdafx.h
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <atlwin.h>
//... ommited headers
```

(`CDialogImpl` is a template class defined in one of the ATL headers referenced by `stdafx.h`)

So what is going on here?  From the context of `myInclude.cpp`, I can see how everything works -- `CDialogImpl` is being brought in via `stdafx.h`, and the declaration of `MyDlg` is being brought in via `myInclude.h`; But how is `myInclude.h` able to resolve `CDialogImpl` by bringing the include into `myInclude.cpp`?

I prefer to keep my includes in `.cpp` files for performance reasons so this is a great feature to know about...but I want to make sure I understand what is happening before I begin using it everywhere.

Questions:

1. Is `myInclude.h` really somehow able to "see" the `myInclude.cpp` file directives?
2. Or is this a weird artifact of how IntelliSense works?
3. If it isn't related to IntelliSense, is it standardized C++ behavior that will work in other compilers (g++, etc.)?

Comment: Files don't have eyes, so none of them *sees* the other. The IDE has a compiler (in some languages, it's known as the *kibitz* compiler) that compiles code in memory and has knowledge of symbols - that's how Intellisense works.

Comment: I guess I'm confused why including myInclude.h in myInclude.cpp enables myInclude.h to see the header in stdafx.h since no include was specified within myInclude.h?

Comment: As I said, the background compiler has knowledge of symbols. It knows that a symbol it found is defined in stdafx.h and has realized that you've not included it where it's needed, so it's telling you how to fix it before the actual compiler is run and an error occurs. That's how Intellisense works - it was designed to do just that sort of thing to locate symbols that are available. It's an IDE/compiler specific functionality; the Delphi and C++Builder IDEs have similar (but not exactly the same) functionality as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation;  I think I'm beginning to understand. So it's more of a check where the background compiler sees a symbol that isn't accessible (in this case within the header) and if the header doesn't have any references to it that triggers the warning...but once at least one reference to the header is added (so that the stdafx.h file becomes accessible) then the error goes away?  I wonder if I had a second cpp file that included the header but didn't include the stdafx header if it would retain the warning in the header file?